# How large would and asteroid need to be to cause damaging earthquakes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, collision, estimation, asteroids

Reading this acticle [www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/huge-asteroid-could-cause-earthquakes-7019482](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/huge-asteroid-could-cause-earthquakes-7019482) I was surprised at the claim that a 2.4km wide asteroid could cause earthquakes on earth by way of a near-miss. Of course, I have no questions regarding what would happen if it was actually a hit ...

The first line states "[...] so big some claim its gravitational pull could cause earthquakes and volcanoes on Earth [...]"

Is this claim based on any actual data or just lies "for the views" ?

If this claim is true I would expect mountains, which I assume are generally larger than this asteroid in volume and mass, to have a visible effect on the landscape through the same "gravitational pull".

This claim seems even more surprising considering that $g = GM/r^2$ implies that strength of the "gravitational pull" decreases with the inverse of the square of the distance. If that asteroid can cause earthquakes, why don't mountains bend trees and pull houses ?

Comment: Also, note how "some claim" doesn't actually give any names, making it somewhat hard to read papers from these people who "made" this claim

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: Well I did try but ... I don't really know what I'm actually doing. (I have very little formal training in science & mathematics, most of what I "know" comes from "surface level" youtube videos ...
I found a study that may link the moon to the intensity of earthquakes
But I can't really find any help in making the calculation myself. I probably don't know what to actually search for, because all my googling has been dead ends so far. 

If I had any idea how to relate a shift in stresses in the crust to the likelyhood of it producing an earthquake, but i can't find that either ...

Comment: So far, every time I had a question of this sort to ask the internet it had either already been answered dozens of time (and so I found the answer myself) or it had such a big flaw in its basic concept that I couldn't find anything about it, 'cause it was dumb.
So I'm starting to think that I might need to rethink the whole problem, or just let it go. The lack of information about it might mean the question is plain stupid